# Rotating Shape with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, kineticjs

I'm struggling to implement a little things on canvas with KineticJS.

I want to create a circle + a line which form a group (plane).
The next step is to allow the group to rotate around itself with a button that appears when you click on the group.

My issue is that when I click on the rotate button, it does not rotate near the button but elsewhere. Have a look :
My rotation atm : http://hpics.li/b46b73a
I want the rotate button to be near the end of the line. Not far away..

I tried to implement it on jsfiddle but I'm kinda new and I didn't manage to put it correctly , if you could help me on that, I would be thankful !
http://jsfiddle.net/49nn0ydh/1/

```
  function radians (degrees) {return degrees * (Math.PI/180)}
  function degrees (radians) {return radians * (180/Math.PI)}

  function angle (cx, cy, px, py) {var x = cx - px; var y = cy - py; return Math.atan2 (-y, -x)}
  function distance (p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y) {return Math.sqrt (Math.pow ((p2x - p1x), 2) + Math.pow ((p2y - p1y), 2))}


  jQuery (function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage ({container: 'kineticDiv', width: 1200, height:600})
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer(); stage.add (layer)


   // group avion1
    var groupPlane1 = new Kinetic.Group ({
      x: 150, y: 150,
      draggable:true
    }); layer.add (groupPlane1)

    // avion 1
    var plane1 = new Kinetic.Circle({

        radius: 10,
        stroke: "darkgreen",
        strokeWidth: 3,
      }); groupPlane1.add(plane1);

      var trackPlane1 = new Kinetic.Line({
      points: [10, 0, 110, 0],
        stroke: "darkgreen",
        strokeWidth: 2
      }); groupPlane1.add(trackPlane1);

   groupPlane1.on('click', function() {
              controlGroup.show();
            });
    groupPlane1.setOffset (plane1.getWidth() * plane1.getScale().x / 2, plane1.getHeight() * plane1.getScale().y / 2)




        var controlGroup = new Kinetic.Group ({
          x: groupPlane1.getPosition().x + 120,
          y: groupPlane1.getPosition().y ,
          opacity: 1, draggable: true,
        }); layer.add (controlGroup)
         var signRect2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x:-8,y: -6,
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          fill: 'white',
          opacity:0
        });
        controlGroup.add(signRect2);

        var sign = new Kinetic.Path({
          x: -10, y: -10,
          data: 'M12.582,9.551C3.251,16.237,0.921,29.021,7.08,38.564l-2.36,1.689l4.893,2.262l4.893,2.262l-0.568-5.36l-0.567-5.359l-2.365,1.694c-4.657-7.375-2.83-17.185,4.352-22.33c7.451-5.338,17.817-3.625,23.156,3.824c5.337,7.449,3.625,17.813-3.821,23.152l2.857,3.988c9.617-6.893,11.827-20.277,4.935-29.896C35.591,4.87,22.204,2.658,12.582,9.551z',
          scale: {x:0.5, y:0.5}, fill: 'black'
        }); controlGroup.add (sign)



        controlGroup.setDragBoundFunc (function (pos) {
          var groupPos = groupPlane1.getPosition();
          var rotation = degrees (angle (groupPos.x, groupPos.y, pos.x, pos.y));
          var dis = distance (groupPos.x, groupPos.y, pos.x, pos.y);
          groupPlane1.setRotationDeg (rotation);
          layer.draw()
          return pos
        })


        controlGroup.on ('dragend', function() {

          controlGroup.hide();
          layer.draw()
        })

        controlGroup.hide();
        layer.draw()
      })
```

Comment: Rotating differs with the center of rotation. KineticJS takes the most left-upper point of your group as the center. If you want to change the center, you could write your own rotate function over the KineticJS's one.

Comment: My rotation is good. The problem is the starting point of my

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust the rotation point by setting the offsetX and offsetY of the group.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @KishorSubedi I am providing an answer to the question and I'm not critiquing or requesting clarification ;-) There are 2 properties on KineticJS objects that allow you to set its rotation point: offsetX and offsetY. The questioner can set those properties to achieve their desired result of "rotating the button near the end of the line...Not far away." See this link in the Konva (formerly KineticJS) documentation: http://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Group.html#toc77

Comment: Sorry, but a suggestion please add the detail or chunk of code so that it might look like an real answer.

Comment: An good answer doesn't have to "look like a real answer", it just needs to be helpful in solving the problem at hand.

Comment: The rotation was already adjusted by offsetX & offsetY but this thing is still a mess... :/

Anyway, I decided to proceed differently : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750822/kineticjs-draw-line-with-mouse-event